# Пойдет ОЗУ ddr3

Tags: пк

Подойдет озу типа ddr3 на материнскую плату asus m4a785-m?

Comment: Нужно посмотреть описание платы на сайте производителя или продавца. Передайте эту мудрость остальным.

Comment: считаю вопросы вида "давайте  я погуглю за вас" нужно закрывать и удалять

Comment: Есть по крайней мере 2 вида этих плат (asus m4a785-m) одна (SocketAM2+) для [DDR2](https://www.nix.ru/autocatalog/motherboards_asustek/ASUS-M4A785-M-RTL-SocketAM2-plus-AMD-785G-PCI-E-plus-SVGA-DVI-HDMI-plus-GbLAN-SATA-RAID-MicroATX-4DDR2_88732.html#), а другая (SocketAM3) для [DDR3](https://www.nix.ru/autocatalog/motherboards_asustek/ASUS-M4A785T-M-RTL-SocketAM3-AMD-785G-PCI-E-plus-SVGA-DVI-HDMI-plus-GbLAN-SATA-RAID-MicroATX-4DDR3_88734.html). Внимательно посмотрите на свою спецификацию

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете установить модули DDR2 DIMM объемом 512 МБ, 1 ГБ, 2 ГБ и 4 ГБ без буфера ECC и non-ECC.
в гнезда DIMM.

```
Dual-channel memory architecture
4 x 240-pin DIMM slots support maximum 16GB unbuffered ECC
and non-ECC DDR2 1200(O.C.)/1066/800/667MHz memory
modules
* We recommend that you install the DDR2 1200(O.C.) DIMMs on
the blue slots for better performance.
** DDR2 1200(O.C.)/1066 is supported by AM3/AM2+ CPU only.
*** Due to AM3/AM2+ CPU limitation, only one DDR2
1200(O.C.)/1066 is supported per channel.
```

Comment: Автор вопроса спрашивал про `DDR3`, если её нельзя, напишите это тоже в ответе, а то непонятно )